# Datagrid don't show elements MVVM

Tags: wpf

I am trying to load a list in my datagrid when pressing the button but it does not show anything.

Do you know where the error is?

Thanks a lot

```html
<UserControl x:Class="HiberusHubClient.View.RatesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HiberusHubClient.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="RatesViewControl"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             DataContext="RatesViewControlDataContext">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment = "Left">
            <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Width="100" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Content="Update" Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" />

            <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                <DataGrid Width="200" Height="400" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding  LstConvertRates,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="lstDataGrid" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>



   public partial class RatesView : UserControl
    {
        public RatesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ConvertRatesViewModel();
        }
    }


ConvertRate.cs
  public class ConvertRate
{
}

public class ConvertRates : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string currencyFrom;
    private string currencyTo;
    private string rate;

    public string CurrencyFrom
    {
        get
        {
            return currencyFrom;
        }

        set
        {
            if (currencyFrom != value)
            {
                currencyFrom = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrencyFrom");
            }
        }
    }

    public string CurrencyTo
    {
        get { return currencyTo; }

        set
        {
            if (currencyTo != value)
            {
                currencyTo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrencyTo");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Rate
    {
        get { return rate; }

        set
        {
            if (rate != value)
            {
                rate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Rate");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}


ConvertRatesViewModel .cs
internal class ConvertRatesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ConvertRates> lstConvertRates;

    public ObservableCollection<ConvertRates> LstConvertRates
    {
        get
        {
            return lstConvertRates;
        }
        set
        {
            lstConvertRates = value;
            //if u want Observable Collection to get updated on edit either
            RaisePropertyChanged("LstConvertRates");
        }
    }

    public void getConvertRates()
    {
        HiberusHubeReference.RequestHubeRestService hiberusHubeReference = new HiberusHubeReference.RequestHubeRestService();

        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string aa = json.Serialize(hiberusHubeReference.RequestRates());
        ObservableCollection<ConvertRates> oMycustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ConvertRates>>(aa);

        LstConvertRates = oMycustomclassname;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    private ICommand mUpdater;

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new Updater();
            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;
        }
    }
}

internal class Updater : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ConvertRatesViewModel convertRatesViewModel = new ConvertRatesViewModel();
        convertRatesViewModel.getConvertRates();
    }
}
```

Comment: The button performs its function correctly, the problem is that once my list is recovered, it is not shown later in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `DataContext` in code behind then there is no need to set `DataContext` also in xaml. You can remove `DataContext="RatesViewControlDataContext"` from RatesView.xaml. Btw. `DataContext="RatesViewControlDataContext"` means `DataContext` property is set to string `"RatesViewControlDataContext"`. You probably don't this.

Try to use existing implementation of `ICommand` interface like `RelayCommand`.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

For your `UpdateCommand` you can modify the setter and create a new instance of `RelayCommand`. In the constructor you can specify whether the command should be executed and which method on your `ConvertRatesViewModel` will be called when you press `btnUpdate` button.

```
private ICommand mUpdater;

public ICommand UpdateCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (mUpdater == null)
            mUpdater = new RelayCommand(x => true, x => getConvertRates());
        return mUpdater;
    }
    set
    {
        mUpdater = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The button performs its function correctly, the problem is that once my list is recovered, it is not shown later in the datagrid.

Comment: @alejandroMartinezFaci What do you mean by "list is recovered"?